# MathJax not working on Mobile application

Tags: bug, mathjax

On Stack Exchange Mobile Application, MathJax is not working.
[image]
As we see here, MathJax is shown as pure text.
Since that the article renders the MathJax properly, the mobile application has the ability to render MathJax.
Is this a programming mistake, or is there a reason of this?

Comment: It might be useful to add either ([meta-tag:ios-app]) or ([meta-tag:android-app]) tag, to clarify which one you're talking about.

Comment: Anyway, if this is about MathJax in *titles*, this seems to be a known problem: [MathJax borks in titles in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221927) and [Please add TeX rendering in titles on the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231730). And since [app development is currently frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming/300389#300389), it seems unlikely that this is going to change.